How to create a plugin website without Google Extensions?
I am looking for a way to program a type of .exe executable that when opened is activated so that when entering a specific web page it inserts the code that I want to change the layout or implement some functionality. This can easily be done by programming something like a Google extension, but what I'm looking for is to do it a little more locally using an exe. What suggestions do you have for me or what I could research to come up with something like this?
I tried to use google extensions

You can write a local proxy server and set the browser to use it.

"a little more local" - you can load a local unpacked extension into Chrome while in developer mode, or you can install Tampermonkey and locally install a userscript for it.

There is no direct way to modify a website's content without using an extension.
The best way to approach your issue would likely be to use an extension that interfaces with your local app. There's several ways to enable this communication:

Set up your local app to create a local web server for your extension to interface using simple http requests
Check out native messaging, it may suit your application

Regardless, you will need to use an extension alongside your app to achieve this.
